# GitLab CI invalidates JMeter command with spaces

Tags: jmeter, gitlab, escaping, gitlab-ci, spaces

Here is a snippet of my `git-ci.yml` file:

```
image:
  name: justb4/jmeter:latest
  entrypoint: [""]
api test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mkdir xyzresults
    - /entrypoint.sh -n -t ./XYZ_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_XYZ.jmx -l ./dcs.log -f -Jthreads=40 -Jrampup=40 -JtestCases=100 -JBASE_URL_2=qa2s.nayax.com -e -o ./dcsresults -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Actor|Actor - Update Work Hours)(-success|-failure)?$"
```

This fails with the error:

```
Error: Malformed option -
```

Note that this **does** work successfully if I just remove `Actor - Update Work Hours`.

This leads me to conclude that I am not escaping the space correctly.

#### Also tried but did not work

1. `'"(Actor|etc.)?$"'`  - single-quote
2. `\"...`  - slash before "
3. `'/entrypoint.sh -n -t ./XYZ_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_XYZ.jmx ... (-success|-failure)?$"'`

   a. this resulted in the last 2 double-quotes not appearing.

Picture shows that the string should be getting passed correctly.

[image]

Comment: you could try to wrap the whole command in single quotes like `'/entrypoint.sh ....'` - we also use this for curl commands from time to time

Comment: @SimonSchrottner - that didn't work, but thanks for the try.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping in single quotes only `Actor - Update Work Hours`? Something like: `/entrypoint.sh -n -t ./XYZ_login_dashboard_machine_actor_card_XYZ.jmx -l ./dcs.log -f -Jthreads=40 -Jrampup=40 -JtestCases=100 -JBASE_URL_2=qa2s.nayax.com -e -o ./dcsresults -Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Actor|'Actor - Update Work Hours')(-success|-failure)?$"`

Comment: @DanielCampos - :-) Yes, I even tried that!  I thought of one more idea: set the property in JMeter itself using the BeanShell thing.  Worth a try, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka - simply add a new **properties** file and add the **-q** parameter to the **jmeter** command.

Worked exactly as expected.

So something like this:

```
jmeter blah blah -q report_filter.properties
```

#### report_filter.properties

```
jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^(Actor|Actor - Update Work Hours|Actor Get|Actor Seach etc. etc. etc.)(-success|-failure)?$
```

Note that you should **not** surround the string with double-quotes.

Enjoy.